# Injective inclusion map from RKHS function space to $L_p(\mu)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, kernels

Let $X$ be a measurable space, $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $X$, and $H$ be a separable reproducing kernel Hilbert space over $X$ with a measurable kernel $k$.

At a certain part in a proof I am reading there is the condition

$S_k : L_q (\mu) \to H $ has a dense image if and only if $id: H \to L_p(\mu)$ is injective.

We know (it is shown in the proof) $id$ is the inclusion operator and is continuous. $S_k$ is the adjoint of the inclusion operator. And $H$ consists if $p$-integrable functions.

My question is how can the inclusion mapping $id$ *always* be injective? $H$ is a Hilbert space of function and $L_p(\mu)$ is a space of **equivalence classes** of functions. I am really confused on the intuition here.

Consider the following:

- I take the function $f \in H$. I know $f$ belongs to some element of $L_p$ and is measurable. Thus the inclusion makes sense.
- The inclusion maps $f$ to its equivalence class $[f]$
- Say I take a measurable $p$-integrable function $g$ which equals $f$ almost everywhere. (I am obviously assuming such a function exists in $H$).
- We see the inclusion maps $g$ to $[f]$.
- Therefore the inclusion map can't be injective

I could see that this can fail if no such function $g$ exists in $H$. (For example if the RKHS $H$ has a *continuous* kernel then every $f \in H$ is continuous and the $g$ in question could not be found.) But I have no reason to believe that such a $g$ can't exist. I am obviously suffering from a knowledge gap. Where am I going wrong in how I am thinking about this.

**PS:** The proof can be found on page 126 here: [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=HUnqnrpYt4IC&lpg=PP1&dq=support%20vector%20machines&pg=PA126#v=onepage&q=support%20vector%20machines&f=false)

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question?  If, for instance, all the functions in $H$ are continuous, the inclusion map will be injective.  For a concrete example, take $X = [0,1]$ and let $H = H^1([0,1])$ be the Hilbert space of all absolutely continuous $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ having $f' \in L^2([0,1],m)$, equipped with the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle_H = \int_0^1 (fg + f'g')\,dm$.

Comment: So I guess I am confused as to what you are really asking.  Certainly the inclusion map *can* be injective.  There doesn't seem to be any assertion that it is *always* injective.

Comment: @NateEldredge The assertion is the the inclusion map is *always* injective. If the kernel is continuous (which means all functions in $H$ are continuous, then yes we have injectivity.) If the kernel is * measurable* then we can only say that each $f \in H$ is measurable.

Comment: I don't see that assertion in what you've written; is it elsewhere in the text?  The line you quote after "At a certain point" is an if and only if statement.  It doesn't assert that the map *is* injective.  If there is an assertion, somewhere, that the inclusion map is always injective, then it must follow from other conditions you have not mentioned.

Comment: @NateEldredge, thanks for clarifying! I wasn't familiar with this class of spaces.

Comment: @NateEldredge Good lord I think you are right. I have been up too late I supposed :( Please post this as a question and I will accept it. Also I linked to the original theorem if you would like to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, from comments, that the question is based on a misreading.  The text does not assert that the inclusion map is always injective; it only gives a necessary and sufficient condition for the map to be injective.  It is easy to find examples where it is, and examples where it isn't.

As an incredibly trivial example, let $H = \mathbb{R}$ with its usual inner product, considered as the RKHS of real-valued functions on a one-point set $X = \{x\}$.  (The reproducing kernel is $k(x,x) = 1$.) If $\mu$ is a measure on $X$ assigning positive mass to $x$, then the inclusion $H \to L^2(X,\mu)$ is injective.  If $\nu$ is the zero measure, then the inclusion $H \to L^2(X,\nu)$ is not injective.